# Multiple RewriteRule conflicts in .htaccess

Tags: php, angularjs, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

We have updated our html website to angularjs app. The app uses css and js files from index.html so we need .htaccess entry for that.
We all so need to setup 301 redirect in htaccess to remove .html in every page to keep old seo benefits. The following htaccess entries works as expected 
if used separately, but it conflicts when we use both. Please help.

EX.
http://example.com/demopage.html should redirect to http://example.com/demopage

```
RewriteEngine on
# To Load css and js from index.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]

# To Remove .html from every page
RewriteRule (.+)\.html$ /$1 [L,R]
```

Comment: Try this:
`RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]`

Comment: prgj83, This too works when used separately but not redirects when `RewriteEngine on

# To Load css and js from index.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]`